# Scope and Claims (again!)

Tags: claims-based-identity, openid-connect, identityserver3, oauth-2.0

I'd like to ask a question to confirm my understanding of how to use Scopes and Claims (roles). Let's say I have a User (User A with read only rights i.e. suitable read only role), a Windows Service (Client A with read only access), an MVC site (Client B with full access), and a Web API. I want the Web API to be accessed by Users and Clients with full access and read only access.

1. I create two Scopes "sampleApi.full and "sampleApi.read_only"
2. I create two Roles "full_access" and "read_only"
3. I configure the Web API with RequiredScopes = new[]{"sampleApi.full", "sampleApi.read_only"}

When Client A connects to the Web API, it passes an Access Token containing Scope "sampleApi.read_only" and I can use [ScopeAuthorize("sampleApi.full)] or ScopeAuthorize("sampleApi.full, sampleApi.read_only")] on my Classes and Methods to fine tune accessibility. No problem.

However, when User A logs in, then he/she "inherits" the Scopes of Client B. So the Access Token contains "sampleApi.full", "sampleApi.read_only", and Role "read_only".

Now I have a problem at the WebApi in that I need to act differently when being called by a User. In that case I ignore the Scopes and use his/her Roles and the User gets "read_only" access which is what I want.

That being correct, it no longer makes sense to use the ScopeAuthorize attribute, and I need a custom hybrid attribute that does something along the lines:

If Caller is a User
     - then use Roles to determine accessibility
Else
     - use Scopes to determine accessibility

or have I completely misunderstood?

Answer (score 11):

Scopes model what a client (not user) is allowed to access. They are manifest as claims in the token. The user's claims are also in the token. Authorization in the resource will be based on a combination of what the client is allowed to do and what the user is allowed to do. That's it.